# VBA Range function suddenly accepts only localized arguments (pt-BR)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the brazilian-portuguese version of Excel on a Windows 7 also pt-BR.
I have a spreadsheet that I use for months in the same machine, same excel version, same etc. and a vba code that worked until today. As far as I know I have changed nothing.

The code was: Range("tabReport[[#All],[Valor]]")
Today when i ran the macro it gave me an error: Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

After several trial and error I corrected to: Range("tabReport[[#Tudo];[Valor]]")

Notes: 
1) "Tudo" is "All" translated to pt-BR.
2) Comma "," became semicolon ";", the equivalent in pt-BR local syntax.

What bugs me is this change from nowhere, that could affect other workbooks. 
Also I prefer mantain my macro in USA English (Global) syntax mode, so it's easier to google and mantain.

Anyone have a clue about how can I control this behavior?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Your best bet may be to access the range via the parent `ListObject` instead.

Comment: In Excel the parameter separator character is dictated in Windows by "Region and Language -> Additional Settings -> List Separator".  This is updated automatically for formulas _already present inside workbooks_ but _will not be updated_ within strings in macros if changed

Comment: @Rory I tried with this: ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Relatório mês").ListObjects("tabReport").ListColumns("Valor") but it's a ListColumn object and excel complains about data type.

Comment: @chancea I checked my list separator, it is semicolon, but it always was. Also, Range used to accept only US syntax, local wasn't allowed until today that is enforced!

Comment: Solved closing and reopening excel. I will voteup your bug sugestion @Rory, because is what appears to be.