# Range accepts sometimes only semicolons instead of commas

Tags: vba, excel

I have reduced my problem to the following code example. I am using a German Excel version in which separators in normal Excel formulas are semicolons ";" instead of "," (e.g. `=SUMME(A1;A3)` instead of `=SUM(A1,A3)`). 
 
Now the code which works different from time to time:

```
Sub CommasDoNotWorkAnymore()

Dim a()
Dim i%

a = Array("A1,A3,A5", "B1", "B2")
i = 0

Debug.Print Sheets(1).Range(a(i)).Address
End Sub
```

Normally, when starting Excel, this code works. But sometimes Excel seem to switch the accepted separators used in the `Range()` to semicolons untill I restart Excel. This occurs most times when rerunning the code after a runtime error.

Is this a general Excel bug? Does anybody know what is behind this behaviour? Is there some Excel-wide "local option" for the `Range` class?

EDIT: I just tried to convert the `a(i)` with `CStr(a(i)` but this does also not work. So no ByRef kind of problem...

Comment: Looks like this has been noticed before: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832281/vba-range-function-suddenly-accepts-only-localized-arguments-pt-br)

Comment: My Excel UI uses semicolons, too. but your code works flawlessly for me. When you get error click Debug button and use Immediate Window to query relevant variables

Comment: The German version of Excel uses the `;` instead of `,` as a separator in lists because the `,` is already taken as a decimal separator in Germany since `one half` is written `0,5` instead of `0.5`. I am mentioning this because you are saying that *sometimes* this is happening. So, I'd like to ask you to check the `Application.DecimalSeparator` whenever this happens. If the `,` works the `Application.DecimalSeparator` should be `.`. But if it doesn't work anymore and instead requires a `;` I am assuming that the `DecimalSeparator` also changed to `,`.

Comment: If that's the case then you could just switch it back to solve the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652409/using-vba-to-detect-which-decimal-sign-the-computer-is-using

Comment: Ok thank you already for your suggestions @Ralph . The *sometimes* means that it is hard to replicate the error. `Application.DecimalSeparator` did not change and was always set to `,`. I did not try to temporarily change the decimal separator though. @user3598756 Essentially the `Range("A1,A3,A5")` part cannot be evaluated.

Comment: Why don't you just `split` all strings in the array on `,` to avoid all problems? Of course, these ranges are later used in the code some place and hence the access to the sheets would be greatly increased. But with `Application.ScreenUpdating` it might not be that bad.

Comment: I loop through the array and I don't want to implement another loop inside to keep the code simple. Splitting the array in advance will also not help because the range strings are related to another array which determines what to do with the corresponding range. But I also want to understand what is happening there. I will try `Application.International(xlAlternateArraySeparator)` and all other separators next time the error occurs and compare it with the standard adjustment when starting Excel.

Comment: Also no change in any `Application.International` separators. Seems like an Excel bug...

Comment: Stealing @JackTheFruit thought.  Maybe you can split your array using `Application.International(xlListSeparator)` instead of an explicit `,` This returns a comma "," in my US version of excel.  Perhaps it will return a semi-colon ";" in the German version.

Comment: Can you write what is expected results after running your code. When I run it nothing happens. Can you write if you feel that the problem is with list separator in VBA array or in list separator in "A1,A3,A5" part?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control it, check first what separator is currently in use. What I guess is that you want to know the list separator:

```
Application.International(xlListSeparator)
```

Check other separators here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-international-property-excel

The other time I had a problem with identifying decimal separator in VBA. Finnally I was able to get it in this way:

```
Function GetVBAdecimalSep()
    Dim a(0) As Variant
    a(0) = 1 / 2
    GetVBAdecimalSep = Mid(a(0), 2, 1)
End Function
```

Changing separator not always works. Please see this: [Changing decimal separator in VBA (not only in Excel)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29131805/1903793)

The best solution is to check/change locale, even temporary.

`Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)`

gives the LCID which would be 1033 for English (US)